# After open a Data Module I got [firedac][phys][ora]-1309. oci is not properly installed

Tags: oracle, delphi, firedac

I configured Firedac to work with Oracle 11g on Windows 7 machine. I installed Oracle Instant Client 32bits files : oci.dll , oraocci11.dll, oraociei11.dll and 
orasql11.dll on the locations :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64

and also in my .exe directory :

..\myapplication\Win64\Debug

..\myapplication\Win32\Debug

When I open the project in Delphi , and run for the first time , it works fne.

However, after I opened a datamodule  and try to run I got the error :
[firedac][phys][ora]-1309. oci is not properly installed in this machine.

Why is this happenning only after open a datamodule ?

I appreciate any help to fix it !

Comment: This q needs an MCVE - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MartynA , I'd really appreciate to be able to present more details regarding this issue, but it seems to be most probably an installation/configuration issue  than a  programming issue, I can't figure out what else can I post here to make my issue clear. Can you suggest me any additional information to post ?  Thks for our attention !

Answer (score 2):

After checking with other support sites and documents, I tried a different configuration that is probably the solution.
When compiling Delphi to win64, Firedac Oracle client files should also be for Win64, so I downloaded Oracle Client 11g for Windows x64 from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html  and copied the new files files oci.dll , oraocci11.dll, oraociei11.dll and orasql11.dll to the locations

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin

Then I can compile and run my Win64 applications with no trouble anymore.

Comment: For the future, you can always use `where.exe` in windows to quickly check if a DLL can be found properly. It searches the current directory and all entries of your `PATH` environment variable.